# Ajax to read PHP

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I think I'm getting ahead of myself, but I tried AJAX tutorials to read from a PHP file. The PHP file simply has an echo statement for the time, and I want to pass that to initialize a javascript clock.

But this is my first time trying AJAX and I can't even seem to get it to activate a test alert message.

Here is the code, it's at the bottom of my PHP page after all of the PHP.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function CheckForChange(){
    //alert("4 and 4");
    //if (4 == 1){
        //setInterval("alert('Yup, it is 1')", 5000);

        //alert('Now it is changed');
    //}

    var ajaxReady = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajaxReady.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (ajaxReady.readystate == 4){
            //Get the data
            //document.getElementById('clocktxt').innerHTML = ajaxReady.responseText;
            alert("here");
            alert(ajaxReady.responseText);
        }
    }
    ajaxReady.open("GET","ServerTime.php",true);
    ajaxReady.send(null);
}

setInterval("CheckForChange()", 7000);
</script>
```

Can somebody tell me why this isn't working? No idea what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Why do you think it isn't working?

Comment: If it were working I'd get an alert saying "here" every 7 seconds. Nothing happens after 7 seconds

Comment: I don't understand *Here is the code, it's at the bottom of my PHP page after all of the PHP.* You are saying you have this `<script>` in  PHP file?? Is it being echo'd properly on the HTML side of the page, or do you actually literally have this code as written at the bottom of a PHP file?? Please clarify.

Comment: It's a PHP page with HTML, and the PHP section is closed before where the script is. The rest of the page where the script is located is HTML. To clarify, the PHP writes part of the HTML, but some is just straight HTML

Comment: What about some firebug?

Comment: Just a note: Don't send strings to `setInterval`, it uses `eval`.  Send functions instead: `setInterval(CheckForChange, 7000);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code is an uncapitalized letter.  (Oops!)  You check `ajaxReady.readystate`; you need to check `ajaxReady.readyState`.

Because `ajaxReady.readystate` will *always* be undefined, your alerts never fire.

[Here's your code fixed and working.](http://jsfiddle.net/josh3736/uqvjv/)

---

As an aside, have you considered using a library to handle the ugliness of cross-browser XHR?  jQuery is your friend:

```
function CheckForChange(){
    $.get('ServerTime.php', function(data) {
        $('#clocktxt').text(data);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. This question has taught me so much and are you serious??? Jquery can reduce all that to 3 lines? Unbelievable. I barely know jquery

Answer (score 0):

You should probably have something like:

```
setInterval(CheckForChange, 7000);
```

On an unrelated note, it's common naming convension in JavaScript to have function and methods names' first letters not capitalized, and the rest is in camelCase. i.e. `checkForChange()`.

Comment: You can do it his way too. I use both ways.

Comment: Truth is correct, @Hope4You.  Using strings in `setTimeout`/`setInterval` is the moral equivalent of using `eval`, [which is a very bad thing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Don't_use_eval!).  **Do not pass a string to `setInterval`.**

Comment: @josh3736: Indeed, but it isn't the **cause** of the problem at hand. I'll leave it here as reference though.

Comment: For my reference, can you explain why quotes are bad to use? I like using them sometimes to pass variables into the function :)

Comment: @Hope4You: josh posted a very helpful link in his comment.

Comment: The link doesn't explain why it's a problem. Is it a security issue?

Comment: @Hope4You, because you're effectively using `eval()`.  The [linked](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Don't_use_eval!) MDN page lists reasons why this is bad, among which are the fact you break scope (`eval`ed code *always* runs in global scope), performance, and security.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the exact problem with your code; here's what I use -- I'm sure it will work for you. (plus, it works with more browsers)

```
var xhr = false;
function CheckForChange(){
    /* Create xhr, which is the making of the object to request an external file */
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }else{
        if(window.ActiveXObject){
            try {
                xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }catch(e){}
        }
    }
    /* End creating xhr */

    /* Retrieve external file, and go to a function once its loading state has changed. */
    if(xhr){
        xhr.onreadystatechange = showContents;
        xhr.open("GET", "ServerTime.php", true);
        xhr.send(null);
    }else{
        //XMLHTTPRequest was never created. Can create an alert box if wanted.
    }
    /* End retrieve external file. */

}

function showContents(){
    if(xhr.readyState==4){
        if(xhr.status==200){
            alert(xhr.responseText);
        }else{
            //Error. Can create an alert box if wanted.
        }
    }
}

setInterval(CheckForChange, 7000);
```